# DJI SDK UI: Customizing contentViewController in DULDefaultViewController

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I am using DJI SDK iOS 4.2.2 with DJI UILibrary 4.2 (with Swift)

I want to replace the default FPV view in DULDefaultView/DULDefaultViewController with a custom map view, which the API reference suggests is possible. I have not been able to find any examples of how to do this in the documentation, or in the iOS sample code. How can I accomplish this?

I have tried overriding the property contentViewController in my View Controller inherited from DULDefaultViewController to no avail (it still loads with the FPV view).

It seems to me the API designers have intended for a simple method to do this, but I just can't see it.

Comment: I'm using objective-c, but I am after the same thing... have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No, my current solution is simply programatically removing the view in viewDidLoad. This does obviously remove the view from the display, but I suspect resources are still used to update the (removed) view, as the FPV View Controller probably still holds a reference to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My app is kinda resource heavy, so I ended up giving up and rebuilding the view from collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 4.2.2 it's not something that can be done.

EDIT: This was added in 4.3:

```
 // Toggle for the content view for our button.  This will swap between our red view controller and the fpv view controller.
    @IBAction func switchContent(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (isContentViewSwitched) {
            isContentViewSwitched = false
            self.contentViewController = self.oldContentViewController
        } else {
            isContentViewSwitched = true
            let newContentViewController = UIViewController()
            newContentViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.oldContentViewController = self.contentViewController as? DULFPVViewController
            self.contentViewController = newContentViewController
        }

    }
```

For the full version, see this [sample code](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UILibrary-iOS/blob/master/Sample%20Code/SwiftSampleCode/UILib%20Sample/DefaultLayoutCustomizationViewController.swift).